# When did other superheroes and the public find out Tony Stark was Iron Man?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

While reading some Silver Age Avengers comics, I realised that back then the public and indeed the other Avengers did not know Tony Stark was Iron man, instead believing he was Iron Man's representative or assistant (or something similar.)

My question is, when did the other superheroes of the Marvel universe find out Tony Stark was Iron Man and when did the public discover this? Comic not movie canon answers please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stark revealed his identity to the world by becoming Iron-Man during a press conference in order to save a dog.

[image: Iron Man 1]
[image: Iron Man 2]
[image: Iron Man 3]
[image: Iron Man 4]

This occurs in *[Iron Man, volume 3, #55/400](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man_Vol_3_55)*, from July, 2002.

Answer (score 0):

I know Thor was one of the first to know Tony Stark was Iron Man, though I'm not sure exactly when (it was pre-1980). Bethany Cabe found out by observation, so wasn't surprised when Madame Masque (former love interest) revealed the secret to her.

Eventually it was reaching a point where the only people who didn't know the super hero's "secret identities" were each other: you know, the ones you would think they would be able to trust after all that time..

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! To improve this answer, please cite source(s) for your statements that Thor was one of the first to know, etc. The question is also asking for when the *public* found out, and I don't see that answered here (other than a vague "eventually").